# Graph with at most 2 degrees of separation between every node, but minimal average degree

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a simple way to construct such a graph? For example a fully connected graph obviously has degree of separation between every node of 1 but has maximal total degree. I can sort of see an algorithm starting with a cycle5 graph and adding nodes until the degree of separation between each pair of nodes is <= 2, but not sure if this would be optimal.

Comment: As this question is not a programming question per se, it would be better suited at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net) or the [computer science stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, if the number of nodes is not constrained to be constant, the answer is a square / triangle / pair of 2 connected nodes. If the number of nodes is given and constant, I think the answer is a star graph.

Comment: Thanks, I realize im actually trying to minimise the average (not total) degree, I was thinking algorithmically about the problem so asked it here, but I will post to mathoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question (yet).